# how to write list into csv columns without brackets?

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to make a csv, where each row contains certain "single" variables (photo_paths[i], i, p, norm_ratio) and then many columns of list items (point_values).

```
face_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
face_writer.writerow([photo_paths[i], i, p, norm_ratio, point_values])
```

the resulting first and last items in the list contain brackets and a vertical bar:

```
|[20.426487199475673
 5986.817702828149]|
```

all the others in the middle are fine.

how do I get rid of those symbols?

Comment: you can do `"".join(photo_paths[i]` to turn it into a string and for the `|` believe that's because of `quotechar='|'` so you could also try `"".join(photo_paths[i].replace('|','')` or change to `quotechar='"'`

Comment: photo_paths isn't the list, the list is point_values
tried that and got:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: `"".join(photo_paths[i]).replace('|','')` should work now

Comment: and you could actually change to `" ".join(point_values).replace('|','')` to space out the values

Comment: I got this:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `writerow()` should be a 1-dimensional list of all the fields. `point_values` is a list, and you're nesting it inside the list. You shold concatenate it instead:

```
face_writer.writerow([photo_paths[i], i, p, norm_ratio] + point_values)
```